# Pyinstaller .exe file gives ModuleNotFoundError: No module named

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pyinstaller, modulenotfounderror

I have created a python (Tkinter) application. The structure is like this:

```
Folder1
      |--module1.py
      |--module2.py
Folder2
      |--module3.py
      |
      .
      .
 .
 .
 .
main.py
```

There are around 6 folders with many modules, main.py accesses Folder1's modules and Folder1 accesses every other Folder's(2,3,4,5) modules.
I want to create a exe file. I used pyinstaller and used `pyinstaller --windowed --noconsole --onefile main.py`. When I click the exe file, I get no module found error.

I tried `--path` and `--hidden imports`, but I get the same error.

- There are `__init__` files for every folder except main.py.
- When I wanted to import modules from other folders, I used to get errors. So I used     sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.getcwd() , "moduleName")) in main.py.
- I didn't use any env, I would just type pip install in a cmd and continue.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

I checked existing problems in stack overflow and they said to use --path and hiddenImports But I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `--add-data` to include those folders into the executable.

For Windows platform:

```
pyinstaller ... --add-data=Folder1;Folder1 --add-data=Folder2;Folder2 main.py
```

For Linux-like platforms:

```
pyinstaller ... --add-data=Folder1:Folder1 --add-data=Folder2:Folder2 main.py
```

Refer to official [document](https://pyinstaller.org/en/v4.2/usage.html) for details.